# How to make repeated content control through OpenDoPE add-in

Tags: ms-word, openxml, docx4j

I have table with one row of content controls. I need to repeat the row as per the data xml using OpenDoPE add-in of MS Word

See the below table and xml mapping which I have done.

[image]

Currently there is one row node in xml so one row of content-control is enough. But when I add more row nodes in xml the content control is not repeating.

Help me to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the "first/oldest" AddIn from https://opendope.org/implementations.html

There is a description of how to use it at http://www.opendope.org/WordAddIn_walkthrough.pdf

But you are probably better off using http://www.opendope.org/downloads/authoring-friendly/setup.exe which uses the drag/drop approach Microsoft introduced in Word 2013.

This answer uses that. (Before installing it, first uninstall the old one, using Windows "Programs and Features").

Using sample XML:

```
<myxml>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <name>Abh</name>
      <company>Standout</company>
      <designation>Dev</designation>
    </row>
    <row>
      <name>Name2</name>
      <company>Co2</company>
      <designation>Design2</designation>
    </row>
  </rows>
</myxml>
```

(note the rows element) and name, company and designation already mapped as per your question:

[image]

select the table row, then in the XML Mapping task pane, right click on row (ie the first of the siblings to be repeated, not the parent), choose Repeat > Insert Content Control:

[image]

In Design Mode, you should now see:
[image]

(note the od:repeat around the three table cells)

Save the docx, then you can try using https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlBindingExtensionsOld.java  (update line 69 to point at your docx).

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i do the same with the  "first/oldest" AddIn what I'm using.

Comment: This walkthrough.pdf is not explaining the design part (How the content controls should be configured in the input template docx)

Answer (score 0):

Any way I found myself a solution to this. The problem was regarding the designing of repeated content control in my template docx. I just created a rich text content control and placed my entire row (which contains the name, company, designation content controls) inside it and mapped as repeated. This resolved my problem. See the below content control design

[image]

Here is the xml mapping of name field

[image]

here is the xml mapping of repeated content controll (row)

[image]